# Flink: Is it possible to provide or assign a time stamp to the checkpoint?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Flink: Is it possible to provide or assign a time stamp to the checkpoint folder like appending a timestamp of last checkpoint to the folder named with job id? Is it possible to give custom name to external checkpoint of each job? If yes , how?

Answer (score 0):

Its looks like you can only set the root [directory path](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/state/checkpoints.html#directory-structure) and then the chekpoint data is written as follow .

```
/user-defined-checkpoint-dir
    /{job-id}
        |
        + --shared/
        + --taskowned/
        + --chk-1/
        + --chk-2/
        + --chk-3/
        ...
```